# facebook fan page wall post via php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using php-sdk-4 for facebook wall posting using my app credential. Everything is working fine. Problem is only posting on user facebook wall or through user post on his facebook fan page wall working but when I used his facebook fan page secret code for publish a post on facebook fan wall then show me error :-

```
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

- My facebook app in testing mode
- I am doing all these steps as admin.
  In my project I want functionality user come login through facebook and select his facebook fan page and publish some text or image on his facebook fan page

Code :-

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'app_id'=>'XXXXXXXXXX',
      'app_secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
));

$graph_url_pages = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$accessToken;
$pages = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url_pages)); // get all pages information from above url.
for($i=0;$i<count($pages->data);$i++)
{
    $page_token = $pages->data[$i]->access_token;
    $pageId = $pages->data[$i]->id;

    $params = array(
       'access_token' => $page_token,
       'from' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
       'to' => $pageId,
       'message' => 'Google Inc',
       'link' => 'http://www.google.com/',
    );

    try {
      $response = $facebook->post('/'.$pageId.'/feed', $params);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
     echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
    }

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    print_r($graphNode);die;

}
```

In code when I passed access_token then show me error but when I passed $accessToken (user access token) then user post going on facebook fan page wall but I want facebook fan page publish a post on timeline.

Comment: Most likely you did not ask for the correct permissions.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for reply but I have already permission like manage_pages, publish pages in my testing Facebook APP.

Comment: then you are most likely not using a page token

Comment: btw, you should not use file_get_contents if you are using the facebook sdk anyway...

Comment: @luschn Thanks for reply. Can you tell me How I can get all pages access_token ? or give me any example because I am bit confused ?

Comment: /me/accounts - it looks like you are doing it right, but you need to debug your token. btw, this looks like spamming, you really want to post the exact same stuff on all pages you manage?

Comment: what for are you using the "to" and "from" parameters? those do not exist according to the docs.

Comment: @luschn Thanks for reply.I want when user select page then he publish post on selected page wall.. "to" and "from" just debuging code.

Comment: either way, debug your access token. and remove the "to" and "from" parameters.

Comment: @luschn already do it as same doc but still same error...

Comment: @luschn and CBroe Thanks for reply. My issue fixed. Its' permission problem.  When I debug the user permissions. Then I got it I forgot the  "publish_pages"  permission. Now Finally Everything is working great :)